# Table cell with ellipsis malfunctioning

Tags: html, css

I have a table that needs to stretch 100% of the page. The first column is set up with an ellipsis on the text content for when the browser is resized. It works, but there is a blank 200px block to the right of the table cell (the width is determined from my CSS width calc of 100% - 200px).

```css
.ff_table {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .ff_table_td1 {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: calc(100% - 200px);
 }
 .ff_table_td2,
 .ff_table_td3 {
   width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<table class="ff_table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="ff_table_td1">thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogtwice</td>
    <td class="ff_table_td2">thequickbrown</td>
    <td class="ff_table_td3">thequickbrown</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so what exactly is your problem? Sorry, not too sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you run my code snippet you'll see an empty white box to the right of the first cell. I can't figure out how to make this not be there.

Comment: Why is your last CSS selector `.ff_table_td2, .ff_table_td2`?

Comment: That was an error.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and i realised what your problem was.

Remove the spaces from `width: calc(100% - 200px);`

```
width: calc(100%-200px);
```

the spaces mess with the css.

However, this still allows for 100% of your cell length, hence you dont see the ellipsis. Change the `width` to 90% and you will see that its still there.

Therefore, you'll need something called a media query in ur css.

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
   .ff_table_td1 { width:200px; }
}
```

This allows you to change the widths of the columns when your browser is below a certain width. You may put any condition you wish in there.

---

Comment: This gets rid of the extra box but then the text stops ellipsising.

Comment: the ellipsising is working. Its because your width of your cell still allows for 100% of your text width. try using the media query in your css. needs a bit of experimenting tho.